# How can we fix bootstrap affix issue which sticks navbar fine at the top, but moves/floats to left (upon scrolling)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have a menu bar to get stick to top when user scrolls up.  It sticks fine at the top.  But, it floats to left.

code: http://www.bootply.com/y801SV4HAu

How to fix menu so that if sticks to top and center (margin-left is currently set to auto to make it center)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container" style="padding:0">
  <div id="menu-header" class="affix">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container"> 
            <span style="color:white">Menu bar here<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i></span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above does what you want it to do. Cassie was correct in suggesting a container div, but with the added style `padding:0` for the way you want it to look. so that it aligns with page title.

Answer (score 0):

When position: fixed is applied to the header upon scrolling down, the margin: auto no longer affects it, so it moves back over to the side. You'll have to find another way to center that div. There are probably a ton of ways to do this; the simplest offhand might be to put it inside a .container div.